# Why is there no difference in these 2 pointer adresses?

Tags: c, pointers

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct lin_list{
    char* payload;
    struct lin_list* next;
}LinListCell, *LinList_p;
```

and this is my main, containing the needed information to show you my problem:

```
int main(void){
    LinList_p linlistpointer;

    char payLoad[80+1];
    strcpy(payLoad,"Test");

    printf("%X\n\n",linlistpointer);

    linlistpointer = LinListInsertFirst(linlistpointer,LinListAllocCell(payLoad));
    linlistpointer = LinListInsertFirst(linlistpointer,LinListAllocCell(payLoad));
    linlistpointer = LinListInsertFirst(linlistpointer,LinListAllocCell(payLoad));
    listLists(linlistpointer);
    linlistpointer = LinListExtractFirst(linlistpointer);
}
```

These are the functions from my main.

```
LinList_p LinListInsertFirst(LinList_p *anchor, LinList_p newcell){
    newcell->next=anchor;
    anchor = newcell;

    printf("\nNew first Element: %X\n\n",anchor);

    printf("\nAnchor: %X\n\n",anchor);
    return anchor;  
}

LinList_p LinListAllocCell(char* payload){
    LinList_p listpointer;
    listpointer = malloc(sizeof(LinListCell));
    listpointer->payload = strdup(payload);
    listpointer->next = NULL;

    printf("New Cell:\nAdress: %X\nPayload: %s\n",listpointer, listpointer->payload);
    return listpointer;
}

void listLists(LinList_p pointer){

    int counter=1;
    LinList_p thispointer = pointer;

    printf("Listlistspointer: %X",pointer);
    printf("\n\n----------------");
    while(thispointer){
        printf("\nNow: #%d\n",counter);
        printf("Adresse: %X\n",thispointer);
        printf("Next: %X\n",thispointer->next);
        printf("Payload: %s\n",thispointer->payload);
        printf("----------------");
        thispointer=thispointer->next;
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

LinList_p LinListExtractFirst(LinList_p *anchor){

    printf("%X",anchor);

    return NULL;

}
```

Note that the LinListExtractFirst is not finished so far, actually I just wanted to check if my pointer was valid and got stuck there, ending up here.

As you can see, one is given a LinList_p* and the other a simple LinList_p.

However, when I try to print out both values via

```
printf("\nAdress: %X\n\n",pointer);
```

in both functions, I get the exact same value in both, which is exactly the same adress as I got in my main function.

Can anyone explain this to me? Both seem to be the same, however I cannot access a struct variable via

```
pointer->variable;
```

in the function which is given a LinList_p*, so there has to be a difference.

I am confused right now...

Comment: Please post a *complete* minimal example.

Comment: Karoly is right: we need to compile this one and look at what is going on.

Comment: To access your strict member via" ->" in the function which is given a LinList_p*, you would do have to dereference the pointer first like this *pointer->variable.

Comment: There ought to be a difference, as one should have the address of a struct (which you could modify), while the other has the address of a pointer, so that you can not only access the struct, but also change the pointer to point somewhere else. Perhaps you passed both of them a pointer to a struct, and didn’t let your compiler report it as an error. Could you post a complete minimal example compiled with strict checks?

Comment: Use `%p` to print out pointer values - `printf( "Address: %p\n", (void *) pointer);` .  This is one of the few times you need to explicitly cast to `void *`.

Comment: Alright, I think I got everything important in there now.

Answer (score 1):

`linlistpointer` is an uninitialized pointer. It's value is undefined and relying on its value is undefined behavior. Everything after that doesn't matter as your program can do just about anything and that be considered fine from the compiler's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a struct has got the same value as a pointer to its first member (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.7.2.1.13).

Just because some `char*` happens to have the same value as a `struct lin_list*` doesn't mean that you can treat it, for all intent and purposes, as a `struct lin_list*`-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't access pointer->variable on the `LinList_p*` is because the compiler treats `LinList_p*` as a pointer-to-a-pointer, regardless of what address is actually being passed in.

It look like you are passing a `LinList_p` to `LinListExtractFirst`, which expects a `LinList_p*`. This is not going to work. You either have to change the signature of `LinListExtractFirst` to take a `LinList_p` or pass in the address of `linlistpointer`:

`linlistpointer = LinListExtractFirst(&linlistpointer);`

depending on what it is you want it to do.

Also, `linlistpointer` is never initialized in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. As it will give you segmentation fault.
Your question's language is ambiguous. But want to know why these two prints in following function. you are printing the both `anchor` values after modification.

If I got your question correctly, `printf("\nNew first Element: %X\n\n",anchor);` should come before modifying the anchor ?

```
LinList_p LinListInsertFirst(LinList_p *anchor, LinList_p newcell){
    newcell->next=anchor;
    anchor = newcell;

    printf("\nNew first Element: %X\n\n",anchor);

    printf("\nAnchor: %X\n\n",anchor);
    return anchor;  
}
```